# Es posible imprimir esto con "for" o de algun otro modo

Tags: java, print

```
package seguimiento;

public class Asteriscos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Asteriscos objAsteriscos=new Asteriscos();
        objAsteriscos.imprimirAsteriscos();

    }
    public void imprimirAsteriscos() {
        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println(" *****************");
        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println(" *****************");
        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println(" *****************");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, puedes hacerlo con un for poniendo en la funcion:

```
for(i=0 ; i<6 ; i++){
   if(i%2==0){
      System.out.println("*****************");
} else {
      System.out.println(" *****************");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu pregunta es como imprimir por pantalla lineas alternas que sean iguales cada dos lineas, puedes hacerlo con un for simplemente mirando si es par o impar, e imprimiendo en consecuencia:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){ // N es el numero de lineas que quieres escribir
    if(i%2 == 0) // Si es par
        System.out.println("*****************");
    else // Si es impar
        System.out.println(" *****************");
}
```